# Finding required sum using break statement python

Tags: python

While doing a python course, I was confused with one code that uses the for loop in python to find the sum of elements that belong to the range. They have included a break statement if the sum = 5 (requires the program to halt if the sum reaches the value 5)
This works in the first code snippet however, the value goes up to 30 in the second code snippet. Why is this happening?

```
>>> sum=0
>>> for m in range(5,11,2):
...     sum+=m
...     if sum==5:
...             break
... 
>>> print(sum)
```

Output- 5

```
>>> sum=0
>>> for z in range(0,11,2):
...     sum+=z
...     if sum==5:
...             break
... 
>>> print(sum)
```

Output- 30

Comment: hello, you should try to do the additions yourself to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: for second snippet, sum never reaches 5

Comment: @impopularGuy Yeah I missed noticing that thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want your code to be:

```
if sum >= 5:
    break
```

`sum` will never equal 5 directly in your second case. If you want to stop when you get *past or equal to* 5, you need the `>=`.

Comment: It works. Thank you. However, why is the sum not 21 in the first code snippet? Does the break statement halt even the for loop?

Comment: @LakshmiVallala Yup, in your first code snippet the sum takes on a value of exactly 5, so your `sum == 5` in the break works there.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list(range(0,11,2))
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

The cumulative sum of these numbers is never five.

Answer (score -1):

You should include the condition as `sum>=5`. So the following code will work

```
 sum=0
 for z in range(0,11,2):
     sum+=z
     if sum>=5:
             break

 print(sum)
```

Your code didn,t work because the sum was never equal to 5 in the second case. It exceeded 5 but never became equal to it.

Comment: @LakshmiVallala Happy to help !  Happy to help ! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as *accepted* by clicking the green check mark.